# Сочетание клавиш в C#

Tags: c#

Скажите, как сделать так, чтобы, например, при нажатии на Ctrl + A + B у меня открывалась Form2? (Она уже создана), просто чтобы никто, кроме тех, кто знает эту комбинацию, не мог открыть эту форму.

Answer (score 2):

```
form.KeyPreview = true;
form.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(Form_KeyDown);
```

где

```
void Form_KeyDown(object o, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    // Ctrl + X     
    if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.X)
    {
        // Выполнить нужное действие, например, открыть форму
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Таким методом не отлавливается тройное нажатие клавиш.
как, например, Control+A+B.

Answer (score 0):

Как насчет [HotKeyEventHandler-а](http://www.greatis.com/dotnet/nostalgia/documentation/T_Greatis_Nostalgia_HotKeyEventHandler.htm)?